# Is it possible to recover a zip file corrupted by GnuPG?

Tags: data-recovery, zip, gnupg

I recently started encrypting a zip file with:

```sh
gpg --symmetric my_file.zip
```

It was taking a long time - the archive is about 300 MB - and so I decided to cancel the operation part way through. The zip file was still there, seemingly untouched, so I thought, stupidly, that I could just cancel the encryption with no consequences. Unfortunately, when I tried to unzip my file, I was then told that it wasn't a valid zip archive.

Is there any way to recover the archive? I also, stupidly, deleted the encrypted file that GnuPG spits out. I have tried `zip -FF my_file.zip`, but it just gives me:

```sh
zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0d 0f on disk 0 at 336338383
```

And then it produces an empty archive.

---

NB: I now believe that the above issues were not caused by GnuPG.

Comment: Are you sure there were no more parameters on the command?

Comment: The only other parameter was `--no-symkey-cache`. But I didn't think that was relevant to this question.

Comment: It isn't relevant. This is strange - gpg is not supposed to modify the input file. Did it change the file's modification date?

Comment: I was messing around with `zip` and `unzip` beforehand. Maybe something got corrupted there? In any case, I seem to have recovered most if not all of the files in the archive using photorec. However, it will be several hours work putting all those files back into the correct folders, and under their correct names.

Comment: While "messing around" you probably overwrote the file.